# Foursquare API and Google maps using Python

Tags: python, google-maps, foursquare

I want to plot Foursquare users check ins listed as longitudes and latitudes on a map ..
I tried to plot them using venus functions but it was not displayed. 
Why? And if I want to connect to google maps, how ??

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

1) Get check-ins from Foursquare

You can get the latitude/longitude coordinates for a user from the checkins endpoint: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/users/checkins

From that response you'll need iterate through the venues to get:

response.checkins.items[i].venue.location.lat

response.checkins.items[i].venue.location.long

2) Plot points on map

If you're making this in Google Apps, you can populate a spreadsheet using the coordinates (and anything else) you got, and produce a map. There's an example with instructions here: http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/spreadsheetsmapwizard/makecustommap.htm